# (C#) What is the fastest way to count byte in a file?

Tags: c#

I want to know a fastest way to count all byte in file ? I need to work on large binary file

I want to know the quantity of all byte in file  (Quantity of 0x00, 0x01, .. 0xff)

It's for add a graph with file representation in my WPF Hexeditor usercontrol https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl like in HxD hexeditor.

This code work fine but it's to slow for large file.

```
public Dictionary<int, long> GetByteCount()
{
    if (IsOpen)
    {
        Position = 0;
        int currentByte = 0;

        // Build dictionary
        Dictionary<int, long> cd = new Dictionary<int, long>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) cd.Add(i, 0);
        //

        for (int i = 0; i <= Length; i++)
        {
            //if (EOF) break;

            currentByte = ReadByte();                    
            if (currentByte != -1) cd[currentByte]++;

            Position++;
        }

        return cd;
    }

    return new Dictionary<int, long>();
}
```

Comment: That code does not *compute sum of all bytes*. It counts characters.

Comment: sorry for my english it's what i want "count all characters" for large file

Comment: What are your performance goals? Is this the bottleneck?

Comment: @CodingYoshi now i can reach 10sec on a 3.5gb file.

Comment: @KenWhite The code operates on bytes rather than characters.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Which is exactly why I posted the comment 4 1/2 months ago, to a prior version (prior to the title edit in revision 5).

Comment: @Ken My point is that there are no characters here or in any of the other revisions

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it's count byte in a stream and not character (sorry for my english). I can change the wrong title of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have optimized David's solution a bit. The "Position" - calls are not necessary. I've found that the buffer length and the unbuffered read mode are not very important, but the "for"- instead of "foreach" - construct in the calculation made a big difference.

Results with

```
foreach (var b in buffer.Take(count))
{
    storedCnt[b]++;
}

file length is 4110217216
duration 00:00:51.1686821
```

Results with

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)  
{
    storedCnt[buffer[i]]++;
}

file length 4110217216
duration 00:00:05.9695418
```

Here the program

```
private static void Main(
{
    const string fileForCheck = @"D:\Data\System\en_visual_studio_enterprise_2015_x86_x64_dvd_6850497.iso";
    Debug.Assert(File.Exists(fileForCheck));

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    var counter = new FileBytesCounter(fileForCheck);
    watch.Start();
    var results = counter.GetByteCount();
    watch.Stop();
    counter.Dispose();

    Console.WriteLine("results:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results.Select((c, b) => $"{b} -> {c}")));
    var sumBytes = results.Sum(c => c);
    Debug.Assert((new FileInfo(fileForCheck)).Length == sumBytes); // here's the proof
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"file length {sumBytes}");
    Console.WriteLine($"duration {watch.Elapsed}");
}
```

and here the class

```
internal class FileBytesCounter
    : FileStream
{
    private const FileOptions FileFlagNoBuffering = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
    private const int CopyBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    //private const int CopyBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 16;

    public FileBytesCounter(string path, FileShare share = FileShare.Read)
        : base(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, share, CopyBufferSize/*, FileFlagNoBuffering*/)
    {
    }

    public long[] GetByteCount()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[CopyBufferSize];
        var storedCnt = new long[256];
        int count;

        Position = 0;

        while ((count = Read(buffer, 0, CopyBufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)  
            {
                storedCnt[buffer[i]]++;
            }
        }

        return storedCnt;
    }
}
```

See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/172613/Fast-File-Copy-With-Managed-Code-UBCopy-update for FileFlagNoBuffering

Comment: A Like your solution Georg, simple and very fast. I have tested and implanted in my project : https://github.com/abbaye/WpfHexEditorControl   Thank for help

Comment: If you want check my github project :) you can like it.

Answer (score 3):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an array of long computing the total of each byte in the file. 
    /// The position of the array makes it possible to obtain the sum of the desired byte
    /// </summary>
    public long[] GetByteCount()
    {
        if (IsOpen)
        {
            const int bufferLenght = 1048576; //1mb
            var storedCnt = new long[256];
            Position = 0;

            while (!Eof)
            {
                var testLenght = Length - Position;
                var buffer = testLenght <= bufferLenght ? new byte[testLenght] : new byte[bufferLenght];

                Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                foreach (var b in buffer)
                    storedCnt[b]++;

                Position += bufferLenght;

            }

            return storedCnt;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Reading in buffers like this is probably the biggest speed up, but you may also get some extra speed by using a simple array of 256 longs, since you know there can only be 256 values. You don't need the extra flexibility and complexity of the Dictionary which lets you store a variable number of values.

Comment: Read should return the number of bytes read, which would be bufferlength OR the remaining bytes. Safer to add that to position then you don't need to adjust for EOF

Comment: This will miscount because you don't allow for the partial buffer read in the final call to `Read`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want something like this:

```
public Dictionary<char, long> GetCharCount(string filePath)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<char, long>();
    var content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    foreach(var c in content)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            result[c] = result[c] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(c, 1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank :) it's work only on text file. I need to work on large binary file